# Как лучше организовать доступ к большому списку строк? Сравнение производительности

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть достаточно большой набор строк (30-40). Необходимо по определенному ключу получать определенную строку. В голову приходит два варианта реализации:

1. Используя switch по ключу получать нужную строку:

   ```
   ...
   switch (key):
     case 'string1':
       return 'some string';
     case 'string2':
       return 'another string';
   ...
   ```
2. Записать строки как значения параметров объекта и по ключу обращаться к ним через квадратные скобки:

   ```
   strings = {
     string1: 'some string',
     string2: 'another string',
     ...
   }
   ...
   return strings[key];
   ```

Какой вариант будет более производительным? Быть может есть более оптимальное решение?

Comment: IndexedDB должны работать быстрее обоих вариантов. Хотя замеры нужны. Если не секрет: что Вы делаете с этими строками, что уперлись в проседание производительности на доступе к строкам по ключу на таком очень-очень маленьком наборе строк (30-40) ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что эта операция имеет большое количество итераций)
Строки используются для создания xml файла по которому в дальнейшем генерируются тайлы через mapnik. Файл может содержать вплоть до нескольких тысяч подобных строк, соответственно и обращений к строкам из этого набора будет столько же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для 30-40 строк уже замучаешься писать switch, проще сразу использовать хэш-таблицу любого вида. То есть второй вариант заведомо удобнее, а потенциально и быстрее, так как хэш-таблица (или объект с динамическими ключами) - встроенная в язык структура.

Comment: Про удобство это точно подмечено, собственно сейчас так и делаю.
Но вот по поводу производительности есть сомнения. Где-то читал, что при обращении к параметрам объекта через квадратные скобки, в отличии от точки, движок не использует ряд оптимизационных процессов. В тоже время switch, (опять же как я  где-то читал) в серверной реализации, при наличии 5 и более вариантов, сам формирует некий кэш-лист.

Comment: "Кэш-лист" и объект со строковыми проперти это примерно одно и то же, только один хардкод, второй создается в рантайме. А обращаться через точку к параметру, имя которого неизвестно на этапе компиляции, в джаваскрипте ЕМНИП нельзя. И даже в случае оптимизированного средствами языка switch-case выполняться будет именно сверка строк, порядок зависит от выбранной реализации раннего отлупа и множества самих строк. А вообще в вашем случае пахнет premature optimization - размышлениями об оптимизации в том месте, где затыка может и не оказаться.